# Как передать значения в поток ввода из Bat файла для вызванного приложения?

Tags: cmd, bat, sqlplus

Запускаю из `bat` файла приложения(например `sqlplus`). После этого хочется передавать значения в поток ввода, чтобы приложение выполняло мои команды.

Таким образом содержимое файла получается таким:

```
sqlplus <данные для подключения>
```

Что надо дописать(если это возможно) чтобы я мог на ввод `sqlplus`'a передавать свои команды, например `select * from dual`;

Интересует именно возможность передачи чего либо на поток ввода.

Comment: `echo "select * from dual;" | sqlplus ...`  В windows возможно без кавычек. только тогда надо разбираться как корректно писать. но подача на стандартый ввод через вертикальную черту должно работать

Comment: @Mike работает. А если я хочу передать больше одной команды?

Comment: думаю он должен понимать через точку с запятой. если это что то другое, то возможно надо будет как то подставить переводы каретки. надо посмотреть как в винде их экранировать, наверное как то можно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сложно, но возможно. Содержимое bat-файла, например, `sqlp.bat`:

```
@echo off
(
    echo select 1 id from dual union all
    echo select 2    from dual
    echo ;
    echo prompt end
) | sqlplus -l -s user/pass@tnsalias
```

Запускаем:

```
C:\> sqlp.bat

        ID
----------
         1
         2

end
```